# Can't load bcmwl (Broadcom Wireless) module in Linux kernel 5.15

Tags: kernel, 22.04, broadcom, linux-headers

The Blackmagic Capture Card kernel module that normally works on Ubuntu 22.04.02, wouldn't work with Linux kernel version 5.19, but works on 5.15. What's really weird, is that even though it works on 5.15, all the other proprietary driver modules won't load on 5.15, not even the nvidia driver, and not even the Broadcom Wireless module (bcmwl-kernel-source). And not even the modules for F2FS file system either...

I have the correct linux-headers for that version too. They're both version 5.15.0-73-generic.

I have tried `sudo modprobe wl`. It doesn't work, it comes up with an error along the lines of: `Unknown symbol or parameter`

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Here's what dmesg said:

```
[  131.818731] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_frame_data (err -2)
[  131.818760] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err -2)
[  131.818791] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err -2)
[  131.818810] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -2)
[  131.818820] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -2)
[  131.818828] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -2)
[  131.818833] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err -2)
[  131.818838] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_gtk_rekey_notify (err -2)
[  131.818845] wl: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -2)
[  131.818854] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err -2)
[  131.818863] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err -2)
[  131.818874] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -2)
[  131.818883] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err -2)
[  131.818890] wl: Unknown symbol ieee80211_freq_khz_to_channel (err -2)
[  131.818913] wl: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -2)
[  131.818919] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err -2)
[  131.818926] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_data (err -2)
[  131.818934] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_done (err -2)
[  131.818939] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -2)
[  204.089758] audit: type=1400 audit(1687069707.207:188): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/19361/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=5938 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  204.089764] audit: type=1400 audit(1687069707.207:189): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/19361/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=5938 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
```

Is there anything I'm missing? What does it mean by "Unknown symbol or parameter" when using modprobe? I really need to know!

Thank you so much!

Comment: I suspect that you inadvertantly installed a conflicting driver that installs its own versions of cfg80211 and others. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dkms status`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found the issue! It was because `linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-73-generic` wasn't installed, that explains why the modules couldn't find the symbols and parameters.